# Having error: Invalid Initializer member when reading from input and trying to put into int array

Tags: c#

I cannot figure out this error for the life of me. I am trying to build a Dictionary in my Player Class. I am reading from an input file and the part of the buffer that goes into the array is a group of numbers. Here's that code:

```
public void BuildPlayers()
    {
        using (StreamReader inFile = new StreamReader("players.txt"))
        {
            //A buffer array of strings to hold each line of code
            string[] Buffer;
            Buffer = inFile.ReadLine().Split('  ');

            //while the buffer isn't empty
            while (Buffer != null)
            {
                //Create an Item class object from the data in the file
                Player placeholder = new Player()
                {
                    playerID = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[0]),
                    playerName = Buffer[1],
                    playerRace = (Race)Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[2]),
                    playerLevel = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[3]),
                    playerExp = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[4]),
                    playerGuildID = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[5]),
                    playerGear[0] = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[6])
                };
```

The problem is that playerGear[0] is giving me that error. I cannot understand why. I've tried making a new array but that doesn't work. Here is where I declare the array:

```
 public Player()
    {
        playerID = 0;
        playerName = null;
        playerRace = (Race)0;
        playerLevel = 0;
        playerExp = 0;
        playerGuildID = 0;
        playerGear = null;

    }

    //Alternate Constructor 
    public Player(uint newExp, uint newGuildID, uint newLevel, uint[] newGear, uint newPlayerID, string newName, Race newRace)
    {
        playerRace = newRace;
        playerExp = newExp;
        playerGuildID = newGuildID;
        playerLevel = newLevel;
        playerGear = newGear;
        playerID = newPlayerID;
        playerName = newName;
    }
```

Comment: off-topic comment have you heard about JSON? or XML? or databases?

Answer (score 2):

Using initializer syntax you can only set **full properties or fields** such as `playerGuildID` or even `playerGear`, but not indexed elements such as `playerGear[0]` or other nested properties.

Possible workaround:

```
Player placeholder = new Player()
{
    playerID = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[0]),
    // ...
    playerGuildID = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[5])
};
placeholder.playerGear[0] = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[6]);
```

The above assumes that **`playerGear`** *has already been intialized to an array of at least 1 item* in the constructor.

If that assumption isn't valid, you can instead choose to assign an array:

```
Player placeholder = new Player()
{
    playerID = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[0]),
    // ...
    playerGuildID = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[5]),
    playerGear = new[] { Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[6]) }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array for your constructor.
So create your `Player` object using the following code.

```
Player placeholder = new Player()
{
   playerID = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[0]),
   playerName = Buffer[1],
   playerRace = (Race)Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[2]),
   playerLevel = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[3]),
   playerExp = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[4]),
   playerGuildID = Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[5]),
   playerGear = new uint[] { Convert.ToUInt32(Buffer[6]) }
};
```